Inject Data into DocuSign Envelope Completed Notification
I want to enhance the text in the notification that goes to the sender after completed envelope.
I have simple envelope with only one signer.
I am using the "captive signing" approach and the Java SDK to prepare the envelope itself (if that matters).
The goal is to have the signer's name into the notification body.
I tried to override the default SenderEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody template and to add
[[Data:SignerName]] or [[Data:SignerEmail]] but they always output to empty.
Could it be that they are not available in the context at that point and is there a way to have at least one of them into that notification?

So you want the body of the email to include the signer name and email address?

At least one of them would be great.

ok, I think your issue is you have to use RecipientEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody and not SenderEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody. One is for the "sender" which is not the signer or recipient, and that seems to be what you want since you want Signer's email and name...

The SenderEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody is the one I need modified. By default it says "All signers completed . I want to have for instance "[[Data:SignerName]] with email [[Data:SignerEmail]] completed ". I am able to modify it and see my changes reflected, but  get only "with email completed " as output. I.e. SignerName and SignerEmail are empty or not getting populated.

That is the email to the sender, so it cannot know what is the signer email or name. Not clear why you say you need to modify this one.

Did you try to modify the one I suggested?

I am creating the envelopes programmatically and I create bunch of them per day. It would be much easier for the guy that will receive these notifications to have the signer's name in the notification itself instead of having to open the envelope in order to check it. But since you say it is not available at that stage, I think I could live with it

RecipientEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody is the email sent to recipients (signers)
SenderEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody is the email sent to the sender of the envelope, the user that either sent it from the web or the auth user logged in to obtain a token for API calls.
The [[Data:SignerName]] and [[Data:SignerEmail]] elements can only be used with RecipientEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody which is in the context of a signer/recipient.
The reason is that you can have multiple signers, so which one do you mean when you send an email to the sender?

Make sense when see it from this POV. Thanks!
